# Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

help me please. I had some issue with my project.
I got error like this

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4-M1-eap-93
ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4-M1-eap-93
```

in my dependencies gradle module, I write this code

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

this is my buildscript

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

apply from: 'dependecies.gradle'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I using kotlin version 1.3.70 and IDE android studio version 3.5.1

Comment: What version is being used in your buildscript (root project build.gradle)? This version overrides the others if I recall.

Comment: I used 1.3.70 version

Comment: Try to find where the `1.4-M1-eap-93` dependency is being used... Maybe it's used by another dependency? Also you don't need `maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap" }` if you're not using EAP.

Comment: I do not find it

Answer (score -1):

change ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70' to ext.kotlin_version = '1.4-M1'